# $_POST not working with required used in input tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that works flawlessly until I add the `required` attribute to the `input` tag.  Then the form doesn't post.  I'm not sure where in the form the required attribute is breaking the $_POST function but once broken all required attributes have to be removed.  Has anyone experienced this behavior?

The ONLY thing that comes to mind is I have about 17 `<div>` with  `display:none` set.  Using Javascript, when a selection is made from a drop-down `<select>` tag the JavaScript changes the display to `display:block` as each `<div>` has unique set of `<input>` and `<select>` tags based on the building type selected.  All of this is inside  the `<form>` `</form>` tags.

There's nothing special about the `<input>` tags.  Only when I add the `required` attribute to the `<input>` tags inside a `<div>` does it have a problem.

A typical `<input>` tag looks like this:

```
   <input name="total_meters" type="number" id="total_meters" tabindex="20" size="40" min="1" max="99999999999" value="2" />
```

The `required` attribute is going between `<input` and `name`.

I'm asking here before I code my own validation routines.

Comment: You mean that the submit for the form still takes you to another page, just the POST is empty or it's a GET request instead? Or it doesn't submit at all (just stays on the same page)?

Comment: Having `input` elements inside divs with `display: none;` doesn't exempt them from form validation. Make sure any inputs in hidden divs are either disabled while the parent div is hidden or remove the `required` attribute while the parent div is hidden. Your form might not be submitting if any required inputs have empty values but are not visible.

Comment: The `<form>` does not submit at all.  I probably have to disable the `<input>` tags.  The problem is each hidden `<div>` has maybe 6-12 questions where 2 are the same for each `<div>`. If the `<input>` should be disabled when in the `<div>` is hidden then I'll have to code a function for each `<div>` to enable the `<input>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use jQuery function to add attribute "required" to the require input tag or
2. Make multiple form tag and multiple summit button for each div tag and adding attribute "required" into input tag.

Comment: jQuery might be a possible.  I believe if I set the ID of the input tag I could change all input tags collectively.

On a side note the following code will not work on my system:

[link](http://www.tutorialscollection.com/jquery-demo/jquery-demo2.php?ex=42.0_1)